# Error trying to pass a LPARAM when going through windows

Tags: winapi, rust, lparam, windows-rs

I'm trying to go through all windows (using Windows API) and get a list of the windows, but when I try to pass through a vector as a `LPARAM` then I get an error:

> 1. non-primitive cast: *mut Vec<isize> as LPARAM an as expression can only be used to convert between primitive types or to coerce to a specific trait object

Code:

```rust
unsafe {
    let windows: Vec<isize> = vec![];
    let _ = WindowsAndMessaging::EnumWindows(Some(enum_window), &mut windows as *mut Vec<isize> as LPARAM).ok();
};
```

Comment: Standard winapi calls can't take closures.

Comment: If it  can't, then how do I pass a LPARAM

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis there are no closures in the question, so I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74567876/edit) your question to add a full [mre]. In particular what is `enum_windows` and where does `WindowsAndMessaging::EnumWindows` come from? The only `EnumWindows` I could find in `winapi` is [`winuser::EnumWindows`](https://docs.rs/winapi/0.3.9/winapi/um/winuser/fn.EnumWindows.html)…

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38995701/how-do-i-pass-a-closure-through-raw-pointers-as-an-argument-to-a-c-function ?

Comment: [`LPARAM`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/Foundation/struct.LPARAM.html) isn't a primitive type, so the cast fails. Use this instead: `LPARAM(&mut windows as *mut Vec<isize> as isize)` to construct an `LPARAM` that wraps a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error diagnostic contains two vital pieces of information:

1. The expression that failed to compile

   ```rust
   *mut Vec<isize> as LPARAM
   ```
2. The language rule that's being violated

   ```
   an as expression can only be used to convert between primitive types
   ```

Either one is spot-on. With any `*mut _` a primitive type, it necessarily means that [`LPARAM`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/Foundation/struct.LPARAM.html) isn't. And that is correct, too. Like most types that appear in the transformed API surface exposed by the [windows](https://crates.io/crates/windows) crate, `LPARAM` follows the [`newtype` idiom](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/new_types.html).

This prevents common errors where different types share the same underlying type (e.g. `HWND` and `HDC`), but also requires that clients construct values of the wrapper type. Casting won't work, as it would with the [winapi](https://crates.io/crates/winapi) or [windows-sys](https://crates.io/crates/windows-sys) crates (that use type aliases for primitive types instead).

The second argument to `EnumWindows` needs to be

```rust
LPARAM(&mut windows as *mut Vec<isize> as isize)
```